# How to make my OSX app to open files of particular types?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have custom made files that were created by my app. I want to be able to double-click on these files and make them open through my app. How can I achieve this?!

Comment: yeah...looks very the same except that I don't know how to add file types to plist, and the link you posted doesn't talk about it either. Do you know how to do it?! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, choose a unique file name extension for your files.  Then add Info.plist information about that file type.  See [Apple's Info.plist reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html), paying particular attention to the sections on `CFBundleDocumentTypes` and `UTExportedTypeDeclarations`.

Comment: I followed that page and modified plist, but when I double click on the file I want to open with my app it throws me this: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported store type.' terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: @EugeneGordin: Googling "Unsupported store type" leads me to believe that it has to do with Core Data, which I've never used, so I don't think I can help you any further.